# c program for interrupt handler in kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, udp, real-time

client- server communication - client is sender and server is receiver.
when the server receives the data on the ethernet interface(UDP) the kernel in the server is triggered. I am using real time LINUX on the server side.
server(i.e embedded pc target) is handling interrupts to trigger the embedded pc target (conatining rt linux) to gain the attention to execute the newly arrived data. My supervisor said that to write the code in kernel mode and compile with it. Is that possible ?? is my understanding correct ?? if it is correct then where to write the interrupt hanler function in kernel mode and how to compile with the existing kernel code ??

Comment: What kernel version do you use? However, you should start from [this book](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Linux_Kernel_Development.html?id=3MWRMYRwulIC&redir_esc=y).